# How to deploy a "Release" build of an ASP.NET MVC5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, release

So It's the first time I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC application to a Windows host.

I set the compile mode to "Release" in Visual Studio 2015 and I compile it but don't know which folder(s) to zip and upload to server...

I see an obj folder in project directory that has two folder inside it. "Debug" and "Release". I'm not sure about them though.

On the other hand in project directory root, there is a folder with the same name as project, inside it I can see controllers so I'm pretty sure that folder is not a "Release" build.

My host is running Plesk and IIS 8.

What should I do?

Comment: visual studio can handle this.. just right click your project and select "Publish". Then add the credentials and it will publish it for u

Comment: @AwaisMahmood Is it possible to do it without Publish option?

Comment: make a virtual directory in IIS.. and then build the project in release mode. then copy your project folder except models and controllers in inetpub folder on server.

Comment: I would look into using web deploy - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx If you cannot publish direct to the host then you can publish to a zip file which you can then use for deployment on the host server - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356104(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VSG24: Why would you want to not use publish? You can set to publish to the filesystem if you don't want it to move the code directly to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Publish wizard of visual studio. As a shortcut --> Right click on the MVC project and click publish. You will find many option here.

Make sure you configure your publish profile in release mode if you are publishing on server